# Get sequence of locations in a data frame in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have data frame (data.table) that contains locations as follow:

```
user_id   date     location
1       20150101   New York
1       20150102   New York
1       20150103   San Francisco
1       20150104   New York
1       20150105   New York
```

I'd like to get the list of travel locations as follow

```
user_id location_list
1       (New York, San Francisco, New York)
```

How should I go about it using data.table or data.frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split` and apply a fancy function in each subgroup of locations. Input data:

```
df <- data.frame(
   user_id = rep(1,5),
   date = 20150101:20150105,
   location = c("NY", "NY", "SF", "NY", "NY")
)
```

Apply either:

```
res <- sapply(split(df$location, df$user_id), function(x) {
   sprintf("(%s)", paste(unique(x), collapse=", "))
})
data.frame(user_id=names(res), location_list=res)
```

Which gives:

```
  user_id location_list
1       1      (NY, SF)
```

Or:

```
res <- sapply(split(df$location, df$user_id), function(x) {
   sprintf("(%s)", paste(rle(as.character(x))$val, collapse=", "))
})

data.frame(user_id=names(res), location_list=res)
```

which gives:

```
  user_id location_list
1       1  (NY, SF, NY)
```

Comment: This is nice but not very `data.table`ish, maybe something like `DT[ , .(location_list = toString(rle(as.character(location))$val)), by = user_id]`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg: nice alternative. Could you please add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Using the `devel` version of `data.table` i.e. `v1.9.5+` , we can create a grouping variable with `rleid` ("gr"), get the `unique` 'location' by 'user_id' and 'gr', and then `paste` it together (`toString`) by 'user_id'.  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df1)[,gr:= rleid(location)][, unique(location) ,.(user_id, gr)][,
     list(location_list= sprintf('(%s)',toString(V1))), by= user_id]
#   user_id                       location_list
#1:       1 (New York, San Francisco, New York)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(user_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), date =
20150101:20150105, 
location = c("New York", "New York", "San Francisco", "New York", 
"New York")), .Names = c("user_id", "date", "location"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, but It is not using the `gr` to give the `New York` after `San Francisco`

Comment: How about `setDT(df)[, .(location=location[1L]), by=.(user_id, rleid(location))][, .(toString(location)), by=user_id]`

Comment: Not a master, but I did `setDT(df1)[, .(location_list = unique(location)), by = .(user_id, rleid(location))][, toString(location_list), by = user_id]` when I first tried to answer it, but then saw @gagolews solution and gave up. And then saw yours too.